# Would this work as a solid fuel heat engine that didn't need to boil water?

Tags: thermodynamics

[image: ![engine diagram]

Would this engine design work. Is it already a known design.What would be the upsides and downsides? What else would you do?

Air gets compressed by some mechanical compression like a rotary compressor.
Then the air gets heated in a heat exchanger.
Then the air flows into the outer combustion chamber, where it is heated up. Some of the air flows into the inner combustion chamber, with the amount that does so limiting the rate of combustion.

The sooty, carbon monoxide and volatile rich partial combustion products are then fully combusted, making the overall process clean burning.
This high pressure air, which should be rich in CO2 but low in carbon monoxide and aromatics then flows out through a soot trap,  and through an air decompression engine. (like another rotary screw, but this one a decompresser) Then through the other side of the heat exchanger and out the exhaust.

Reason to think it might work. The energy needed to compress a given number of molecules of air is linear in temperature. Combustion of carbon rich fuel doesn't change the number of molecules much, but does increase the temperature, and so the pressure. Thus the amount of energy per molecule is higher on the exiting of the high pressure section than it is on the entrance to the high pressure section.

Comment: Work for what?  I don't see a power output, which is what engines are for.

Comment: @TigerGuy Power output is on the rotating axle. The decompression step should generate more mechanical energy than the compression uses.

Comment: It reminds me of the Brayton-Joule cycle. You can check It out to find similarities, if you haven't already, of course.

Comment: Found this patent. https://www.freepatentsonline.com/4152890.html

Comment: Missing a few key components needed to start and maintain.  Like anything else- it's an engine if you add enough of the right engine parts.

Comment: The devils in the details, but I believe it *can* work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I can see is that there's no valve system to ensure that exhaust gases are directed to the decompressor.  The entire interior of the engine will be at more or less the same pressure.

The pressure of the incoming air and outgoing exhaust will be near enough the same - atmospheric pressure.  But the pressure on the outlet of the compressor and the intake of the decompressor will also be near enough the same.

So the compressor and the decompressor are going to be opposing each other, and you will be lucky to get any useful amount of power out.

Comment: The pressure going out of the compressor and into the decompressor are the same, but the temperature, and therefore volume, differ.

Answer (score 0):

Your design can be approximated using the *Brayton cycle* with recuperation. Search on that for the details.

Answer (score -1):

Every Jet-Engine works like that. They only miss the heat-exchanger.